# What's a more succinct way to bind the same parameter, multiple times, via pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a MySQL query string with a number of unnamed place-holders (`?`), each accepting the same parameter:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value, ".
           "CASE ".
               "WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE ? THEN 1 ".
               "WHEN A1.content LIKE ? THEN 2 ".
               "WHEN A2.value LIKE ? THEN 3 ".
           "END AS rank ".
       "FROM mod_site_content A1 ".
       "LEFT JOIN mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2 ".
           "ON A1.id = A2.contentid ".
           "AND A2.tmplvarid IN(15,17) ".
       "WHERE (pagetitle LIKE ? ".
           "OR content LIKE ? ".
           "OR value LIKE ?) ".
       "ORDER BY rank";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$searchq = "%".$searchq."%";
```

And currently I'm repeating the binds, in what seems like quite a verbose way:

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
...etc
```

Is there a tidier and more maintainable way of binding the same parameter to any number of placeholders?

**EDIT**: php version 5.10.1

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would do.

```
foreach($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
  $stmt->bindParam($i, $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Or, if you have some indices to be left out:

```
foreach($i in range(1,3,4,7)) {
  $stmt->bindParam($i, $searchq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I get a 500 internal error with this. Do you need to see the entire function, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

How about writing the query like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value, 
       (CASE WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE vars.pattern THEN 1 
             WHEN A1.content LIKE vars.pattern THEN 2
             WHEN A2.value LIKE vars.pattern THEN 3
             . . .
       ) as val
FROM . . . CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as pattern) vars
. . .
```

Then you only need to include it once.

EDIT:

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
       (CASE WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE vars.pattern THEN 1
             WHEN A1.content LIKE vars.pattern THEN 2
             WHEN A2.value LIKE vars.pattern THEN 3
        END) AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1 LEFT JOIN
     mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
     ON A1.id = A2.contentid AND A2.tmplvarid IN (15, 17) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as pattern) vars
WHERE (pagetitle LIKE vars.pattern OR content LIKE vars.pattern OR value LIKE vars.pattern);
ORDER BY rank;
```

You can simplify this by using `having`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
       (CASE WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE vars.pattern THEN 1
             WHEN A1.content LIKE vars.pattern THEN 2
             WHEN A2.value LIKE vars.pattern THEN 3
        END) AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1 LEFT JOIN
     mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
     ON A1.id = A2.contentid AND A2.tmplvarid IN (15, 17) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as pattern) vars
HAVING rank > 0
ORDER BY rank;
```

And then, if the "patterns" are not using wildcards, you could just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
       field(vars.pattern, A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A2.value) AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1 LEFT JOIN
     mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
     ON A1.id = A2.contentid AND A2.tmplvarid IN (15, 17) CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT ? as pattern) vars
HAVING rank > 0
ORDER BY rank;
```

At this point, you only have the pattern once, so this should work *if your pattern has no wildcards*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value,
       field(?, A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A2.value) AS rank
FROM mod_site_content A1 LEFT JOIN
     mod_site_tmplvar_contentvalues A2
     ON A1.id = A2.contentid AND A2.tmplvarid IN (15, 17)
HAVING rank > 0
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm not completely sure how I'd implement it properly though (my fault for not including the full query). I've edited my answer to reflect this, if you're able to elaborate on your approach.

Comment: Will have to try these later - thanks for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

With the risk of downvotes since I haven't really TRIED this solution, I'd try something along these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A1.pagetitle, A1.content, A1.uri, A2.value, ".
           "CASE ".
               "WHEN A1.pagetitle LIKE CONCAT('%', :my_str, '%') THEN 1 ".
               "WHEN A1.content LIKE CONCAT('%', :my_str, '%') THEN 2 ".
               "WHEN A2.value LIKE CONCAT('%', :my_str, '%') THEN 3 ".
               ...etc

$pdo->bindValue(':my_str', $stuff);
```

Comment: I think you can't bind named parameters more than once - which is why I'm using the "?" instead.

Comment: I think that was fixed. Could you try to run with this example so we confirm it does or doesn't work for your version of PHP?

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: Fair enough, I'll leave the answer as a warning to other people with similar problems. Could you just add your PHP version? I'll try to run this later with newer versions.

Comment: Yeah no problem - oversight on my part.

Comment: Per PDO docs, it appears this has been fixed in PHP 5.2.1, so if you use version 5.2.1+ you can use above method.